# How do I find if my amplifier compressed the waveform?

Tags: signal-analysis, envelope

I have a waveform that's modulated by a trapezoidal function. I fitted the envelope to the expected function to show if the amplitude is modulated correctly.

[image: Fit of envelope]

I also plotted the difference of the fit and the envelope

[image: Difference fit and envelope]

This is an example of a fairly "healthy" waveform. Sometimes my amplifier likes to compress and decompress the output though, which results in a difference plot like this:

[image: Difference unhealthy envelope]

As you can see the difference doesn't seem to be continuous, and has sudden drops and rises. I want to be able to automatically detect these moments of compression/decompression. How do I show that the data is not "continuous" anymore?

Comment: Do you happen to know something about the spectrum of your signal?

Comment: @Marcus Müller
You mean if I did a fourier transform? I did, but I'm not sure how that helps me in this case?

Comment: compression is a nonlinear operation that happens to your signal, so you can directly observe its presence if you know what an uncompressed spectrum looks like

Comment: @Marcus Müller
Ok interesting! Could you elaborate a bit further? Because I'm not sure if I understand what to do with the spectrum yet

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem with your solution, but I do have to confess that the expected frequency and amplitude of the signal is variable each time the system is pulsed. I do have a data source on the expected frequency variables, but I don't have data on the expected amplitude

Comment: I was assuming that based on the varying amplitude in your plots, which is why I asked about you knowing about the spectral properties of your signal, which might be easier to define :) Generally, editing your question to tell us as much as you can about the original waveform might be really really helpful for finding an easy and robust way.